# Как правильно писать в социальных сетях слово "вы"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Подскажите, как правильно писать "вы" в социальных сетях? Ведь в личной переписке допускается обращаться на "Вы" с большой буквы, а если это социальная сеть, то нужно писать с маленькой или большой? Лично я считаю, что это с большой буквы ровно так же, как в личной переписке, так как идет уважение к читателю, хоть и читает очень много людей, но в контексте идут такие предложения как "что бы Вы сделали" или "как Вы считаете". Понимаю, что эти предложения можно прочитать как во множественном числе, так и в единственном во 2-м лице...

Answer (score 1):

На сайтах, в социальных сетях в объявлениях при обращении к большой аудитории неопределённых людей принято писать ***вы*** с маленькой буквы. Именно потому, что ***не знаешь потенциального читателя*** и обращаешься не к конкретному, а сразу ко многим по отдельности.

[Вот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88) статья на Грамоте *"Как писать ВЫ и ВАШ – с прописной или со строчной буквы?"* Процитирую по теме вопроса:

> При обращении к нескольким лицам или неопределенному кругу лиц (например, при обращении к читательской аудитории газеты или журнала, при обращении к посетителям сайта, в объявлении, адресованном широкому кругу лиц, и т. п.) местоимения *вы, ваш* пишутся со строчной буквы: *Дорогие подписчики! Напоминаем вам, что...; На портале «Грамота.ру» опубликован новый интерактивный диктант. Проверьте вашу грамотность!*

Comment: Артём, извините... Мне _кажется,_ что Ваше **первое** предложение в ответе требует правки. _На сайтах, в социальных сетях в объявлениях при обращению к большой аудитории неопределённых людей принято..._ Нет?.. Я бы поправила — но не хотелось бы испортить Ваше видение.

Comment: А что именно? Ю исправил, что-то ещё?

Comment: Но в социальных сетях возможно и личное обращение (в чате), тогда всё-таки с уважением - с большой буквы...

Comment: Да, конечно, Людмила, я говорил только про объявления, обращённые к неопределённому кругу лиц.

Answer (score 1):

В соцсетях и прочем - я за строчную букву в слове "вы", если только речь не идет об официальном обращении. "Вы"  с заглавной уместно тогда и только тогда, когда письмо начинается со слов *"Милостивый государь!"* или по современному *"Уважаемый пользователь Имерек Батькович!"*. Исключения я делаю (и то чаще забываю) только для лиц, которые прямо обозначили своё иное понимание этого (вот как Людмила).

Попробую объясниться. Вопрос дискутируется очень давно. Ходило в сети даже рукописное письмо самого Розенталя, где он недвусмысленно разрешал писать *вы* со строчной в частной переписке. *(Искать не буду, ибо у моих оппонентов будет законный в общем-то резон спросить "А как это переносится на тексты в Интернете?")* Так вот в те еще времена пришли к выводу, что даже из числа обращенных к одному конкретному лицу 99% процентов текстов в сети носит неформальный характер. Что, конечно, не исключает уважения участников разговора друг к другу, но делает официальное его проявление совсем неуместным. Представьте себе на минуточку, что Филипп Филиппович и Шариков общались бы через Вотс-Ап или Инстаграмм. Стал бы ФФ писать заглавную во фразе "Вы, Шариков, стоите на самой низшей ступени развития!"?! Не думаю (с). Да и Шариков вряд ли бы не отвечал тем же.

Плюс ко всему, можно ли говорить об уважении к конкретному человеку, если все, что мы о нем обычно знаем, - это его сетевой ник-нейм?!